# Difference between undefined and forbidden (division by zero)

Tags: terminology, definition

**Division by zero is undefined**

**Division by zero is not allowed / forbidden**

I wonder if there is a mathematical difference between *undefined* and *forbidden* in the context of division my zero and if so, what's the correct term.

Comment: The division by zero is forbidden to high school students because it is undefined.

Comment: Whether something is forbidden is an ethical question, not a mathematical one

Comment: So, there's no definition of "forbidden" in mathematics?

Comment: "forbidden" is a term one should reserve to young minds and therefore is a more pedagogical term (and maybe a bad one). For someone more mature,  he or she should not divide by zero because it is not yet defined, definitely  not because someone forbade him/her to do so. So no "forbidden" is not mathematical whereas undefined is.

Comment: Well, technically it is not *undefined* because you could define it to anything you like.  The question is however: *"Can you extend the familiar arithmetic rules known from integers, rationals or reals?"*  The answer to that question is "No": However you define the result of operation $x/0$, you'll lose some of the nice properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically it is not *undefined* because you could define it to anything you like.

The question is however: *"Can you extend the familiar arithmetic rules known from integers, rationals or reals to also cover division by zero?"*

The answer to that question is "No": However you define the result of operation $x/0$, you'll lose some of the nice properties. This is also true when you try to extend these numbers to also include $\infty$ and / or $-\infty$ or the like.

In some contexts, like computation, it's common to define $x/0$ to:

- $:=\mathrm{Inf}$ if $0<x<\mathrm{Inf}$ where Inf represents $\infty$.
- $:=-\mathrm{Inf}$ if $\mathrm{Inf}<x<0$.
- $:=\mathrm{NaN}$ if $x=0$ where NaN stands for not-a-number.
  So you can do it technically, but you lose properties like existence of inverse elements of multiplication, inverse elements of addition, [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), etc.